# App not installed shortcut

Tags: android

This is my code to make shortcut on home screen. Everthing works fine but when I click shortcut on home screen it shows "App not installed" . I would like to repair it.

**code**

```
appPref = getSharedPreferences("isFirstTime", 0);
isFirstTime = appPref.getBoolean("isFirstTime", true);

if (isFirstTime) {
    // Create explicit intent which will be used to call Our application
    // when some one clicked on short cut
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    // Create Implicit intent and assign Shortcut Application Name, Icon
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Get Quote");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

    // Set preference to inform that we have created shortcut on
    // Homescreen
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use ApplicationContext, using `this` (Activity) will be fine

I haven't tested this theory, but I would guess your issue is `Intent intent = new Intent();`, Try using a PendingIntent instead

Your shortcutIntent also should take an action specific to your app (or a schema type) or the class you want to open. The action you've provided is generic and may be causing your issue (setting action overrides what you passed in when you created the intent, it's not necessary here)

It's also not a good idea to create a shortcut without asking the user, it may annoy them enough to uninstall it as malware